# Hibernate : Order by a string field as number

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Java Hibernate application,
I have a string column with values like

```
1
2
3
4A
4B
5
6/7
8
11
21
31
```

Actually, these are the number of houses in a colony.
And notice entries like 4A, 6/7 which makes ordering not possible by `cast as int`.

Now, I want exactly the order above, but I am getting the following order.

```
1
11
2
21
3
31
4A
4B
5
6/7
8
```

I want plot number 11, 21, 31 in the end.

Please guide me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I did some work around to this problem. And here is it.

In my case, the first part will essentially be an integer.
So, I create 2 fields for the number in my entity.
`number` as Integer and `subNumber` as String.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUSE")
public class House {

    .....

    @Column(name = "NUMBER")
    private int number;

    @Column(name = "SUB_NUMBER")
    private String subNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TOWN_ID", nullable = false)
    private Town town;

    .....

    public House(int number, String subNumber) {
        this.number = number;
        this.subNumber = subNumber;
    }

    .....

}
```

And, order them as follows in the parent class, that is `Town`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOWN")
public class Town {

    .....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "town")
    @OrderBy(clause = "number, subNumber")
    List<House> houses;

    .....

}
```

Now, when getting input from the user. I separated both parts by pattern matching.
Like below:

```
public House createHouse(String n) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(^\\d+)(.*)").matcher(n);

    if(!m.find()) {
        throw new Exception("Number must start with a digit!");
    }

    int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    String subNumber = m.group(2);

    return new House(number, subNumber);
}
```

That's it. For example:

4A  = number: 4, subNumber = A

6/7 = number: 6, subNumber = /7

And, You will get the right order now.

Even if your problem scenario is a bit different, you can apply same logic
by making two fields. It is very easy then custom HQL or native SQL, don't
know about performance.

Comment: I like the idea of splitting it into two fields as it should be mostly sufficient for house number (so we won't have values like 4/7 and 4/10 appear together :P )  As these two fields is mostly stored for DB sorting purpose, I would suggest to handle it in `@PrePersist` though, so the design do not need to be changed too much (OP may have issue in changing to a factory method for House)

Comment: Well, I am not aware of @PrePersist or what it does. As, I said, it is a work around. Anyway, I will look for it. And what is OP?

Comment: OP means original poster :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have some problem here because it's not automatic that 6/7 should be between 6 and 7 and not be 67.  There won't be any HQL that knows this, so you'll have to write something yourself.  Create a `formula` property in Hibernate that uses native SQL to transform the string into a number the way you want to.  Easiest way might be a regular expression replace that takes only the first non-numeric characters.  Then you can sort on that property.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by having 2 level sorting.

Select * from house where order by length(house_id), house_id;

Comment: This will kind of work assuming all inputs are numbers but not for `4A`, `4B`,  `6/7` will be in the wrong position.

Answer (score -1):

I think this query is working

```
SELECT * FROM orders o ORDER BY o.order
```

This is schema

```
CREATE TABLE `testspring`.`orders`( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,`order` VARCHAR(255) ,     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: Nope, it is giving the same order, the below one. And, I am doing it in hibernate, so I added like this with @OrderBy(clause = "houseNumber") on the field.

Comment: You got your solution? the thing is you have to define your houseNumber column as varchar that's solve

Comment: then it has to come, try with above two queries with your data its working, can you post your hql

Comment: This is it.
Hibernate: select residentia0_.SCHEME_ID as SCHEME3_6_1_, residentia0_.PLOT_ID as PLOT2_5_1_, residentia0_.PLOT_ID as ID1_4_0_, residentia0_1_.NUMBER as NUMBER2_4_0_, residentia0_.AREA as AREA1_5_0_, residentia0_.SCHEME_ID as SCHEME3_5_0_ from RESIDENTIAL_PLOT residentia0_ inner join PLOT residentia0_1_ on residentia0_.PLOT_ID=residentia0_1_.ID where residentia0_.SCHEME_ID=? order by residentia0_1_.NUMBER

Comment: If you're not paying attention to the order, watch the plot number 11 index in both orders. I want plot no. 11 in the end.

Comment: @Akshat under order by use that column name that you want to sort. I worked for me with the above query.

Comment: Which orderby? The @OrderBy(clause) or HQL one?

Comment: HQL one, just work with the simple SQL that I have given their, so you understand and easily convert that in HQL

Comment: I tried, but still the same order. Actually, NUMBER is the column that I want to sort. Same with the order by column in hql given by me. Can it be database specific? Which database are you using? I am using apache derby 10.

Comment: I am using MySQL database, yes might be database specific, I am expecting someone to come and interfere so that I can also learn, That SQL statement is working fine in my DB and with your data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41798/discussion-between-suganthan-and-akshat)